# c# code erroring out on linux for GhostscriptRasterizer

Tags: c#, linux, ghostscript

I am using ghostscript GhostscriptRasterizer to convert pdf pages into png files.
Below is the .net core 3.0 c# code I am using, This works fine on my windows machine. However when i am porting this code to a linux serve, I am getting below error. at this line:

```
rasterizer.Open(folder_path + "/" + pdf_filename, gvi, true);
```

> Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libkernel32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Below is the full code.

```
using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
{
    string binpath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string gsDllPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(binpath, Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "gsdll64.dll" : "gsdll32.dll");
    GhostscriptVersionInfo gvi = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(gsDllPath);
    rasterizer.Open(folder_path + "/" + pdf_filename, gvi, true);
    int PdfPages = rasterizer.PageCount;
    for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= rasterizer.PageCount; pageNumber++)
    {
         Image pdf2PNG = rasterizer.GetPage(200, 200, pageNumber);
         string save_file_name = chart_id.ToString() + "_" + pageNumber.ToString() + ".jpeg";
         pdf2PNG.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder_path, save_file_name), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    rasterizer.Close();
}
```

I have installed GhostScript on linux machine using below command.

```
sudo apt-get install ghostscript
```

What am I doing wrong? With my limited knowledge on ghostscript, I believe `gsdll64.dll` which i am using on windows is not compatible with linux machine. If my understanding is correct, then where can I get the corresponding gsdll64.dll for a linux machine?

Comment: The error message _Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll'_ seems to me to confirm your suspicion that this is an OS issue, as that's of course a Windows system file..

Comment: Are you using Ghostscript.NET? Because that's not net core enabled at all.

Comment: I do have Ghostscript.NET.dll file in bin folder. However i am not sure if this file is even being used in the execution. As said, then code works fine on windows machine.

Comment: _I do have Ghostscript.NET.dll file in bin folder. However i am not sure if this file is even being used in the execution_ - aren't you using [GhostscriptRasterizer](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET/Rasterizer/GhostscriptRasterizer.cs) though? You could check your `using` statements in the code to confirm that. _The code works fine on windows machine._ yes, but the library hasn't really been updated in the last 4 years, so there's not really any chance of it running on .Net Core.

Comment: So it seems to me your choices are: 1) run the code on a windows machine or 2) use a whole different approach, assuming there's one available that suits your needs.

Comment: .. which makes your question unsuitable for Stack Overflow, I'm afraid. But please do follow up with a new question if you go with option 2) and have something specific you're looking for help with.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I am falling back to native ghostscript exe. I am running below command to convert pdf file to jpeg images, No matter what parameters I pass the output images are always of low resolution, like 30kb, I am looking for a better quality images, what parameters should i use. ```gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=page-%d.jpeg -f mypdf.pdf -c quit -r600x600 -dJPEGQ=95```

Comment: You should probably ask a new question, you're more likely to get an answer that way.